# HAML doesn't work on production (it work in development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.1, production-environment

I'm getting missing partial error using HAML on production. It works fine in development (even on production/staging environment on my computer) but I'm getting "Missing partial" on my production server.

Log file - http://pastie.org/2324017
Gemfile - http://pastie.org/2324028

There's another partial 2 lines before _login_form and it's rendered fine (i think so, there's no error).

Any ideas why I'm getting this and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the presence of corresponded file on the server ?

Comment: It expects for .erb or .builder template, not .haml (depending on the log info).

Comment: Ehh, I just needed to do hard restart (kill -9 and then start new instance) of unicorn. Restarting with -USR2 does not load new gems. It works fine now :)

Comment: Please add all the information about your question to the SO site itself instead of linking to an external site.